# How can I store the result of a calculator and return with alert or console.log?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I don't know how to display and store the result answer.

I want to display it with `alert()` or `console.log()`.

Here the code I have tried:

```
a = prompt("Entrez une valeur");
b = prompt("Entrez une deuxieme valeur");
op = prompt("Entrez une opérande");

var answer;

function mycal(a, b, op) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            return answer = a + b
            break;
        case '-':
            return answer = a - b
            break;
        case '*':
            return answer = a * b
            break;
        case '/':
            return answer = a / b
            break;
    }
}

console.log(answer);
```

Comment: Try invoking `mycal` somwhere, first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the global **answer** variable there.

Change your return statements to simply return the result instead of trying to assign it to "answer". ie

```
switch(op){
case '+' : 
  return a+b 
  break;
case '-' : 
  return a-b 
  break;
case '*' : 
  return a*b 
  break;
case '/' : 
  return a/b 
  break;
}
```

then simply change your console.log to be

```
console.log(mycal(a,b,op))
```

If you really want the results to be assigned to **answer** you could do something like

```
var answer = mycal(a,b,op)    
console.log(answer)
```

Comment: You're welcome.. if that answers your question, can you please select it as the answer and mark it as done.

Answer (score 0):

Call `mycal(a,b,op)` inside console.log or alert

```
console.log(mycal(a,b,op)); 
alert(mycal(a,b,op));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnuy7/7640/)